# Can't part of my first plugin (mask) to work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating my first plugin and decided to try and create a mask plugin that would use the `#` character as the mask character. So if I called:

```
 ('input').mask('(###)-###-####');
```

The mask would become `(   )-   -`

All #'s would be replaced by spaces so only the mask would show.  I sort of skipped ahead of this and just wanted to see if as I get the keypress to work.  What I wanted to do was as the user types a character, I want to put there character at the first occurrence of the # character.  This is how I want it to be, the mask starts of as `(   )-   -`.  If the user types a 3, then it should display 
`(3  )-   -`. Next, it might be something like `(35 )-   -`.  This goes on until the mask is complete.  The below scripts is not very good and is probably not the best way to go at it, but just remember I am just trying to learn.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.mask = function(options) {

var
    defaults = {
        mask: '',
        maskColor: '#c4c4c4',
        inputColor: '#000000'
    },
    settings = $.extend({},defaults,options);

    this.keypress(function(e)
    {
        var text = '';
        var length = settings.mask.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var c = settings.mask.charCodeAt(i);

            if(c != '35') //35 is the # character
            {

                text += settings.mask.charAt(i); /*Trying to do (342)-292-2029  
                                                 for example, but after the  
                                                 first character, it does 
                                                 ()-()-()3 instead. */
            }
        }
        $(this).val(text);
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this a little bit here http://jsfiddle.net/gJ68n/  This could certainly be optimized, but I think it might get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: I like it, but it's not really an answer.

Comment: Awesome, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Why use a keyup instead of a keypress or keydown?

Comment: You could probably use any of those.  For some reason, I default to keyup.  Try out different ones and see which one plays better with your page.

Comment: I did and keypress and keydown allow you to enter 5 digits at the end such as 333-333-33333.  Keyup also has a more natural feel to it, although is it possible to prevent the input box from flickering with the last digit.  With keyup, you can enter a 5th digit, but it disappears right afterwards.